# node.js - Displayed page in browser does not change after pushing new code

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04, pm2

I have an 'hello world' Node test app running fine on ubuntu remote server ( Nginx proxy, PM2 managed )

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World');
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

running fine ( locally on ubuntu server :

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080
Hello World
```

and via web browser

When I update the code :

```
 changing to:   res.end('Hello World, again');
```

and pushing it via scp :

```
scp -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -r  hello.js  myself@myRemoteServer:/home/myself
```

hello.js is effectively modified on the remote server , BUT the running Node app hello.js is still displaying the previous text ...

what am I missing to make the new code running ?

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restart the app in order to make it use the new code.

```
pm2 restart hello // or however your app's name is
```

should do the trick after uploading the new files.

There's also an [option](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2#commands-overview) to auto restart your app on file change. For this, start your app with

```
pm2 start hello.js --watch
```

Comment: thanks a lot ... I forgot --watch   , it's now updating , restarting and displaying the new text !!